# How to change input value dynamically

Tags: php, html

I want to change an input value depending on a $_POST variable. Something like this:

```
<?php if ($_POST['yourname'] != "") 
    { 
        $('input[name=yourname]').attr('title', $_POST['yourname']); 
    } ?>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have this input:

```
<input class="clearme" name="yourname" type="text" title="Insert your name"  />
```

Comment: you are mixing serverside and clientside code. php code runs on the server and only the output of it is send to the client (browser) who interprets it afterwards.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Surely you can just request a different POST item based on the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add directly to html:

```
<input class="clearme" name="yourname" type="text" title="Insert your name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['yourname']) ? $_POST['yourname'] : ''; ?>"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use javascript in PHP. PHP runs on the server, while javascript runs in the clients browser.

You need to do this in pure javascript, not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the one file, replacing 'name_of_cur_file.php' with the name of the current php file.:

```
<?php

if($_POST['yourname'] > ""){
$yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
}else{
$yourname = ""; // set to avoid errors
}
?>
<form action="name_of_cur_file.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $yourname;?>" />
<input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

WARNING!!! - Lacking any validation for this example!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code sent from the server to execute then:

```
<?php if ($_POST['yourname'] != "") 
    { 
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('input[name=yourname]').attr('title', $_POST['yourname']);
             });
        </script>
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have jquery code in php.You have complete first php tag then you have write your jquery code in script code like

```
<?php if ($_POST['yourname'] != "") 
    { 
?>
      <script>
        $('input[name=yourname]').attr('title', $_POST['yourname']); 
      </script>
<?php
    } ?>
```

You can also write php code only like

```
 <?php 
$title="Insert your name";
if ($_POST['yourname'] != "") 
        { 

           $title=$_POST['yourname'];

        } ?>

<input class="clearme" name="yourname" type="text" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
```